# Capturing SQL calls sent to a remote server from application

Tags: sql-server

First of all, I'm not well versed in SQL *anything* at all. Closest I've ever needed to get was storing and retrieving data from a local SQLite db.

In essence I think I have a simple problem but it's hard to orient yourself when everything is new.

My main tool at work is an ERP software, which is basically a front end to an SQL db.

Problem I have with it is that it's very clumsy and doesn't allow automation of even the most basic tasks.

What I want to do, is bypass the front-end completely and interact directly with the db to automate most of my tasks with python.

I can connect to the database just fine from python environment, but the schema is gigantic, there's no way I'll be able to find whatever it is I might be looking for.

So I need to capture the call front-end sends when I click a button (telling it to display specific set of data) to use that call as a guide.

Basically, how can I, an SQL noob, capture calls that a desktop application sends to a remote server?

Edit 1: My job is mostly analytical, so all of my automation will be for retrieval, analysis and visualization. I'm not very likely to mess anything up.

Edit 2: Tried running a Profiler and got the message:

"In order to run a trace against SQL Server you must be a member of sysadmin fixed server role or have the ALTER TRACE permission."

I'm not a sysadmin, don't have an alter trace permission and reeeally don't feel like asking for it :D

Comment: Please be _very_ careful with that approach. Who's to say the ERP software doesn't have its internal business logic which breaks on direct DB updates? You _really_ want to ask ERP provider for a supported method to bypass the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL version, you could run a Query Trace or an [Extended Event](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/02/extended-events/capture-queries-sql-server) to capture the TSQL being run by your app.

Comment: Profiler might be of use here too. But I wanted to mainly state these are all Microsoft SQL Server solutions, so @BenTait please tag your appropriate SQL Server version, or if your ERP system doesn't use Microsoft SQL Server, then tag the correlating database management system it does use (e.g. Oracle PL/SQL, or MySQL, or PostgreSQL, etc).

Comment: Profiler is installed with SQL Server Management Studio and is the easiest to use.  With all these you need to be careful not to adversely affect the performance of the system, and the key challenge will be to single-out the single user's activity.  If you have a desktop client for the system, this is easy, but if it uses a web server, it's tricker.